# Apache Kafka Consume from ISR node

Tags: apache-kafka, high-availability

I understand the concept of leaders and data replication in Kafka, but i don't understand why consumers and producers will always be routed to a master node when writing/reading from a partition instead of being able to read from any ISR (in-sync replica)

The way i think about it, if all consumers are redirected to one single master node, then more hardware is required to handle read/write operations from large consumer groups/producers.

Is it possible to read and write in replica nodes or the consumers/producers will always reach out to the master node of that partition?

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka, we have concept of Leader and Follower for a Partition.

All reads/writes for a specific partition happens through 'Leader' of the partition and 'Follower' get in-sync with 'Leader' for updates.

In Kafka, Producer/Consumer or any Client applications will always communicate to 'Leader' of the partition.

If a Leader dies/down for some reason then new Leader will be elected from ISR (In-Sync Replica list)

ISR: Replicas/Followers which has all the updates or in other words which are in-sync with Leader will be elected as a new Leader for the partition.

More details:
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/apache-kafka-quick-start-1edeef53773e

Comment: Why is that? What is the reason why there must be a leader for a partition instead of the consumer being able to actually consume data from any partition since they are all replicated anyway? I dont understand why have it centralized to a single "leader" node instead of allowing the use of the replicas.

Comment: I read that `since Apache Kafka 2.4, it is possible to configure consumers to read from in-sync replicas instead of leader (usually the closest)` - yet to find the consumer settings to make it realised